# Coin-toss game with \$1 entry fee and \$3 payout

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, expectation

Imagine a coin-tossing bet game. You pay \$1 to play the game (for one toss), and if you win you get a prize of \$3. The \$1 to play is not refunded. The probability of winning and losing is equal. If you play the game 100 times, what's the probability that you will have more money than when you started?

I have worked out that the expected value after playing a game is \$1(gaining a dollar per game). Based on this, I couldn't quite figure out the answer to the probability question.

Please explain your answer.

Comment: Let's say you win $k$ out of the $100$ times. What is your net gain? When is this $>0$?

Comment: You would have gained k*$3 - $100. This is greater than 0 if you win more than 33 of the games.

Comment: By playing $100$ games it is going to cost you $\$100.$ Thus, to end with more money you must win at least $\lceil100/3\rceil=34$ games. Each game has equal probability of winning and losing. So we can think of them all as independent coin flips and need at least $34$ heads. The distribution of heads is given by the binomial distribution with probability of success, $p=0.5$ and number of trials, $n=100$. Let $X$ be the number of winsthen the probability you seek is $$\mathbb{P}(X\geq 34) = 1-\mathbb{P}(X\leq33) = 1-\sum_{k=0}^{33}{100\choose k}0.5^k(1-0.5)^{100-k} \approx 0.9996.$$

Comment: As I understand it then, the "game fee" of \$1 is not refunded additional to the \$3 prize if you win, and is all you lose in the case of losing. So your net position is (win = +\$2, lose = -\$1) - correct? Which on 0.5 win probability would be an expected value per game of +\$0.50.

Comment: @Joffan yes, the game fee is not refunded additionally, you lose the $1 fee anyway.

Comment: @David This seems like the correct answer. Thanks!

Comment: @damjandd no problem, sorry that they shut down your question for whatever reason.

Comment: @David This would qualify as a Bernoulli Trials problem, right?

Comment: @damjandd Correct! Each individual game is a Bernoulli Trial, and a Binomial Distribution is simply the distribution for the number of successes when you do a bunch of identical and independent Bernoulli Trials in a row.